# QGIS- Missing measure line box/point during editing

Tags: qgis, line, measurements

I've just updated my QGIS 3.4.4 to QGIS 3.10.8 and now I cannot measure distance and place point on measured distance. As soon as I click on to editing/adding point the measure tool box and line/point disappears.

I know this still works in 3.4.4 but can I somehow make it work in 3.10.8?

Attaching picture from old 3.4.4 QGIS version to better explain what I mean. As you can see on the picture there is still yellow rubberband and an end point on to which I still can snap while adding lines or points.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your needs but it seem that using the advanced digitizing panel in construction mode would allow you to place point at set distance with no need to mesure and great accuracy. There is a youtube tutorial by Klas Karlsson on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZYKGrIyVCA&ab_channel=KlasKarlsson (even if this is not what you need it's an interesting watch for advanced digitizing)

Answer (score 0):

Our workaround is: install the Plugin [ShapeTools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/)

Comment: Could you please add more information?